# Unpacking os.walk inconsistent errors for different filepath

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Basic Python question.

Am playing with `os.walk` function and see inconsistent error messages.
Sample o/p below:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 14:08:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('.')  # ------> **no error**
>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('/')  # ------> **error #1**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('/usr/bin') # ------>**error #2**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
>>>
```

My understanding is `os.walk` returns generator, so error #2 makes sense for me. One generator value is returned, but I'm unpacking to 3 values.

So:

1. Why I don't get any error when I `os.walk('.')`
2. Why error #2 and #1 are different.

EDIT 1:

Played around a bit more and found that the location where python is run affects the execution, since the meaning of "." varies.

```
raghu$ pwd
/Users/raghu/PycharmProjects/Fib
raghu$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 14:08:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('.')  # ------>**no error**
>>> ^D
raghu$ cd ..
raghu$ pwd
/Users/raghu/PycharmProjects
raghu$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 18 2017, 14:08:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('.')  # ------>**error**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you unpack, you exhaust the iterable on the right side. You aren't getting a `dirpath, dirname, filenames` tuple back which you assign to `root, dirs, filenames`.

An attempt to assign the first result (the first yield, that is) of `os.walk(<value)` to `root` is done, then, the second result (second yield) to `dirs` and then, finally, the third yield to `file`. If more results (or less!) are yielded, you get your errors. If exactly three are returned, it seemingly works.

So, in the first case it was simply just luck and `3` results were yielded back to you which got assigned (`3` tuples containing the `dirpath, dirname, filenames`!).

`'/usr/bin'` *usually* doesn't contain any subdirectories, that's why you get the different error there (only 1 three tuple yield is performed).

With `'/'` you also get a greater number of three element tuples returned, so you get the appropriate error.

You can take a glampse of this by examining the number of items the generator yields:

```
>>> from os import walk
>>> len(list(walk('.')))
2300
>>> len(list(walk('/')))  # this is really dumb
127242
>>> len(list(walk('/usr/bin')))
1
```

As you can see in the last example, only one 3-element tuple is yielded. If you find a folder for which the `len(list(walk('folder'))) == 3`, the unpacking will work.

Answer (score 2):

*Each* value produced by (read: while iterating over) `os.walk(...)` is a 3-tuple.  Your code acts like the function returns a *single* such 3-tuple, but what it really means is "expect exactly 3 directories in this directory tree and give (misleading) names to the (tuple of) information about each".

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top
>   itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

So in each of these cases, there may be a different amount of tuples that is yielding which is causing your problems.